# CSS space invader with only one element

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

There is a lot of shapes that we can make with pure CSS, like in http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons/demo/ and you always write one element (here `<li>`).

But if we want shapes that are a little bit more complexe, like http://www.gentegeek.com/proyectos/html-css-space-invaders/ we must put a lot of `<div>` (see the source code).

Can I make shapes with only one element? If yes, how?

Comment: Can I make shapes with only one element?No.now no how arises.

Comment: @Random Okay, but maybe someone else found a way and will share it with us.

Comment: ok check to this i have careated all shape pick one as like you http://tinkerbin.com/glfu6QQK

Comment: By default the shape of element in HTML is rectangular. So using only one elemt for creating different shapes I dont think it can be done.

There is one way to create shapes using one element, by using direct image tag :(

Comment: @Naren Maybe with a lot of `:after` and `:before` ?

Comment: You can only have one `:before` and one `:after` per element. I reckon you'd need *seven* elements to be able to create your example.

Comment: @Random: there is always a may be............
but there is also limitation.

Comment: It's an *interesting* question, but it's also a bit too broad for Stack Overflow IMO.

Comment: @Naren--no limitation in this case.

Comment: @Jeroen--I don't think it is too broad. There is a principle that can apply in multiple cases, and an actual solution to his specific example as well.

Comment: @thirtydot--the key is to not think in elements but in background painting.

Comment: @Random--Not "No," but Yes! And the how is by `linear-gradient` use.

Comment: @ScottS: It didn't even cross my mind to use gradients for this. Kudos for actually recreating the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes! -- With CSS3

***However, it is probably not worth the effort in most cases.*** Essentially, given enough forethought and patience, you can "paint" practically any pixel based shape (like your example) using `linear-gradient`.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PmhJD/25/). (Updated to allow for transparency of image areas itself).

The code is a single `div` element (per your request). The css is as follows (I've not posted all the vendor prefix equivalents here).

```css
div {
    width: 240px;
    height: 160px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0, 0 20px, 0 40px, 0 70px, 0 90px, 0 100px, 0 120px, 0 140px;
    background-size: 240px 20px, 240px 20px, 240px 30px, 240px 20px, 240px 10px, 240px 20px, 240px 20px, 240px 20px;
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(left, transparent 0px, transparent 40px, #000 41px, #000 60px, transparent 61px, transparent 180px, #000 181px, #000 200px, transparent 201px, transparent 240px ),
        linear-gradient(left, #000 0px, #000 20px, transparent 21px, transparent 60px, #000 61px, #000 80px, transparent 81px, transparent 160px, #000 161px, #000 180px, transparent 181px, transparent 220px, #000 221px, #000 240px),
        linear-gradient(left, #000 0px, #000 20px, transparent 21px, transparent 40px, #000 41px, #000 200px, transparent 201px, transparent 220px, #000 221px, #000 240px),
        linear-gradient(left, #000 0px, #000 60px, transparent 61px, transparent 80px, #000 81px, #000 160px, transparent 161px, transparent 180px, #000 181px, #000 240px),
        linear-gradient(left, #000, #000),
        linear-gradient(left, transparent 0px, transparent 20px, #000 21px, #000 220px, transparent 221px, transparent 240px ),
        linear-gradient(left, transparent 0px, transparent 40px, #000 41px, #000 60px, transparent 61px, transparent 180px, #000 181px, #000 200px, transparent 201px, transparent 240px ),
        linear-gradient(left, transparent 0px, transparent 20px, #000 21px, #000 40px, transparent 41px, transparent 200px, #000 201px, #000 220px, transparent 221px, transparent 240px );
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have transparency ?

Comment: @Mageek--Sure, change the `#000` to an `rgba()` color scheme with the alpha transparency and it should work in CSS3 browsers also. [See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PmhJD/38/)